# RSpec/Capybara sends Item to controller and It doesn't find it. Why?

Tags: testing, activerecord, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

My form accepts an id for an object called "Item." The id number is being sent to the controller using AJAX and is supposed to return the item, but the controller is sending back an error saying that it can't find the item even though I just created it with a "let" command.  Here is the test:

```
describe "Manually creates a new clearance_batch", type: :feature do
  let!(:wholesale_price) { 100 }
  let!(:item) { FactoryGirl.create(:item, style: FactoryGirl.create(:style, wholesale_price: wholesale_price)) }

  it "should successfully create a new batch", js: true, :focus => true do
    item.reload
    visit "/clearance_batches/new"
    within('.table_body') do
      expect(page).to_not have_content(item.id)
    end
    element = find('.new_item_box')
    element.set(item.id)
    click_button 'scan'
  end
end
```

And here is the error:

```
Failures:

  1) Manually creates a new clearance_batch should successfully create a new batch
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Item with 'id'=1
     # ./app/controllers/items_controller.rb:18:in `show'

Finished in 2.96 seconds (files took 1.54 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/clearance_batches_spec.rb:96 # Manually creates a new clearance_batch should successfully create a new batch
stitchfix-take-home-challenge [capybara-round-2] :>
```

Comment: Which is line 96 in the spec -- `click_button 'scan'`? If so, what does the `scan` button do?

Comment: Line 96 is just the "it" block. The 'scan' button simply sends the form.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `item.id` within your test?  Also, it would help if you shared your relevant controller code (e.g. related to line 18).

Comment: Setting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` solved a similar issue for me in rails 5.0.6.